# Simple C# Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I would like to be able to output the following format using C# Linq to Xml.

```
<Genres>
<Genre Value="Rock" />
<Genre Value="Metal" />
</Genres>
```

Consider the following function. I want to evaluate each of the parameters but only add the ones that are not empty strings.

```
private XmlElement createGenresXml(string str1 = "", string str2 = "Rock", string str3 = "Metal", string str4 = "")
{
    'Return XmlElement should look like the Xml above.
}
```

Thanks! \m/ \m/

Comment: Stackoverflow does not provide code writing services. If you have a question please feel free. You are most welcome.

Comment: I don't think LINQ is really suited for that task since you have a bunch of independent parameters. Why not just use some `if` to put the element together?

Comment: If you want to use Linq then use `XElement` instead of `XmlElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public XmlElement CreateGenresXml(string[] args)
    {
        var el = new XElement("Genres");
        el.Add(args.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Select(arg => new XElement("Genre", new XAttribute("Value", arg))));
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (var reader = el.CreateReader())
        {
            doc.Load(reader);
        }
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

The conversion to XmlElement borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/rarous/3150395):

Comment: I knew how to accomplish the task by other means but wanted to check out Linq to Xml. Thank you!

Comment: I would change the signature to `CreateGenresXml(params string[] args)` that way you can call it like this `CreateGenresXml("arg1", "arg2", ...)`